# What does this error mean on hackerrank.com?

Tags: python, set, runtime-error

I am doing challenges on hackerrank.com in Python language and I have difficulties with understanding the error message I am receiving.

This is the code:

```
for i in range(1):
    in1 = int(input())
    if in1 > 1000:
        print('error')
        break
    else:
        roll1 = set(input().split())
        in2 = int(input())
    if in2 >  1000:
        print('error')
        break
    else:
        roll2 = set(input().split())
    if len(roll1.union(roll2)) > 1000:
        print('error')
        break
    else:
        print(len(roll1.union(roll2)))
```

This is the error I don't understand:

```
Runtime Error
Error (stderr)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is the input:

```
Input (stdin)
9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
9
10 1 2 3 11 21 55 6 8
```

This is expected output:

```
Expected Output
13
```

I don't expect you to solve for me this challenge. I just don't understand this error message. And it is in my previous solutions too. What it is about?

Thanks :-).

Comment: I got the expected output. Perhaps you have an indentation problem in your original code, it's hard to say because the code here is not formatted properly.

Comment: Can you format your code?

Comment: Ok. I reformat my code. I think that could be the problem. Because I cannot find that challenge now on hackerrank.com because I abandoned it we will never find out :-p. In PyCharm this code gave me positive output so I think it is good. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the error. This code produces an error in Python 2 due to `input()` being defined as `eval(raw_input())`. In Python 3, `raw_input` was renamed as `input`. Adding `input = raw_input` to the top of the program resolves the error. Also running the program under Python 3 does also.

You can produce the same error in both versions with the following:

```
>>> eval("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The presence of `File "<string>", line 1` in the traceback is a sign that the error came from a call to `eval`.

Comment: This is a good solution. I realized that in this hackerrank.com ide I can change the compiler to Python 3. I didn't know that earlier. I also change roll1 = set(int(input().split())) to roll1 = set(input().split()) and now the challenge is accomplished. Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 1):

`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`
python is reading all this as string,
try: 
`listX = list(map(int, input.split()))`

Use the listX where u need

Comment: The challenge was about sets so I think it is not the case but thanks :-).

Comment: try changing ``` roll1 = set(input().split()) ``` to ```roll1 = set(int(input().split()))```

Comment: Tried: roll1 = set(input().split()) ``` to roll1 = set(int(input().split())), still got the same error message. It is strange because in PyCharm I got positive results.

Answer (score 1):

It is an error of python 2 and your code is in python 3 so make sure that u have selected python 3 in hackerrank